# Codeigniter Loop error on DB_driver.php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

I make a clone of my repository in a new computer, after configurating and execute , Codeigniter throws this error (it's try to connect (?) to a SQlServer 2008).

[image]

I tried with IIS and wamp (I increased the value of xdebug, but does not work and trips to infinite loop). On the other hand, increase the memory_limit of php and I get the same result.

With the same configuration, it works on other computers.

I hope you can help me,
regards

Comment: Can you post the code for the `DB_driver.php` and `sqlsrv_driver.php` (on pastebin perhaps, since it looks like it's large)? It looks like the `sqlsrv_driver` is executing a query while it is called from the `DB_driver->initialize()` method, before the initialization is marked complete, causing `simple_query` to call `initialize` again. On these other computers, do you also use that sqlsrv_driver?

Comment: Post controller/model code that is used.

Comment: It happens when you start the application, and used the 'default' scripts of codeigniter